# machine learning multi-class prediction and architecture approaches for reduction of memory (neural networks in keras)

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, lookup

**Main Question:**

Are there other methods (preferably an easily implementable keras model) for training a classifier than outputting a one-hot vector from a neural network?

(i.e. cosine similarity between two vectors that simply outputs the decoded data rather than a large vector - in order to save memory)

**Context**:

I have been trying to train a multi-class classifier in keras but so far the only way I have been able to think of the problem involves having two one-hot vector outputs with ~30,000 values.  These are output from a TimeDistributed Dense layer.

These large tensors cannot be loaded into my GPU (~12 Gb).

The goal is to joint learn relationships and NER.  Specifically, 4 features are learned:

1. A broad classification (such as person, organization, etc.)
2. If the entity is involved in a relationship with another entity (boolean)
3. A specific ID associated with the entity (such as a SSN for a person)
4. The specific ID associated with the other entity if it is in a relationship with another (i.e. Neil P. Harris waved at Jimmy Carter).

I have a dictionary / ontology of key-values for task 3 and 4, but I would like to joint learn the tagging.  The reason for this is because the dictionary may have (in keeping with the example above) something like this:  `{"Neil Patrick Harris":ID001, "James Earl Carter Jr.": ID002}`

Therefore, it would be useful to learn the associations, as clearly searching a dictionary or ontology for `"Neil P. Harris"` when the string `"Neil Patrick Harris"` exists in the dictionary, no results will be found.

The problem is the one hot vector for classification is so large.

This is the model I am working with at the moment (certainly open to suggestions on ways to improve it for this task however)

---

```
____________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
part_of_speech_input (InputLayer)           (None, 60)            0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
words_input (InputLayer)          (None, 60)            0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_2 (Embedding)          (None, 60, 50)        2500        part_of_speech_input[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_1 (Embedding)          (None, 60, 256)       5630720     words_input[0][0]                 
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)      (None, 60, 306)       0           embedding_2[0][0]                
                                                                   embedding_1[0][0]                
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_1 (Bidirectional)  (None, 60, 512)       1153024     concatenate_1[0][0]              
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_2 (Bidirectional)  (None, 60, 4)         8240        bidirectional_1[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_2 (Concatenate)      (None, 60, 516)       0           bidirectional_1[0][0]            
                                                                   bidirectional_2[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_1 (TimeDistribu (None, 60, 3)         1539        bidirectional_1[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_2 (TimeDistribu (None, 60, 2)         10          bidirectional_2[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_3 (TimeDistribu (None, 60, 14245)     7364665     concatenate_2[0][0]              
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_4 (TimeDistribu (None, 60, 14245)     7364665     concatenate_2[0][0]              
====================================================================================================
Total params: 21,525,363
Trainable params: 21,525,363
Non-trainable params: 0
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: what about a huffman coding of your one hot vectors? this is quite common to reduce dimensionality if you have frequency information. Keep in mind that your loss function might change from cross entropy to logloss, can't tell from your model definition.

Comment: I thought about this idea, but wasn't sure of how to implement it.  I'm using crossentropy right now and softmax activation functions for everything. If the switch to a logloss function also includes huffman coding the output strings, how do you get the class associated from yhat (closest match / cosine similarity?)?  The TimeDistributed(Dense()) layer to a onehot vector via argmax of the probabilities is all I know that can get back to the original string via a dictionary so far.  If the yhat is the size of the huffman coding, how do you get back the original str?

Comment: you'd learn the binary code that is basically a sigmoid between 0/1 per bit you need to encode and then you can try to reconstruct using a threshold. If you have the code, you have the dictionary entry as well.

Comment: Are there huffman codings that provide codes that are all the same length?  I coded my strings as huffman encodings but because they're not equal length, the neural network can't take the input/output.  I don't think padding with zero will work since that appears to create overlap between things in the dictionary.